# Change html element id in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html in a variable now i want to change the id of a particular element that is in the jquery variable but i am not able to do that.

HTML

```
<tbody id ="testid">
<tr><td></td><tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="10"  style="font-size:14px;background-color:#5858FA;color: #FFFFFF;cursor:pointer">MYNAME</td>
    <td><input type="text" name ="first_test" id ="test1"></td>
    <td colspan="10"  style="font-size:14px;background-color:#5858FA;color: #FFFFFF;cursor:pointer">CLG</td>
    <td><input type="text" name ="second_test" id ="second2"></td>
    <td colspan="10"  style="font-size:14px;background-color:#5858FA;color: #FFFFFF;cursor:pointer">Address</td>
    <td><input type="text" name ="third_test" id ="second3"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**Code**

```
var xHtml = $('#test_id tr:gt(0)').map(function(){return this.outerHTML;}).get().join('');
xHtml = $(xHtml).find('#td_id').attr('id', 'tdid_test').end().map(function () {alert(this.outerHTML); return this.outerHTML;}).get().join('');
```

After doing this i am getting blank value in the xHtml variable .Please suggest how can we do this

Comment: change the id of which element?? and change it to what?

Comment: xHtml will have html .Now i that html i want to change the td_id id to tdid_test

Comment: u could change it directly via the element itself

Comment: how please tell me because i am putting this varaible html in a new div

Comment: yes like what C-link answer is

Comment: Does $(xHtml).find('#td_id') return the element with id=td_id ?

Comment: What does the html look like? Perhaps you should use filter instead of find. Please output console.log( xHtml ) before and after.

Comment: @user3558931 before i am getting the complete html after that variable have blank value

Comment: Can you post your html? Please.

Comment: @GauravPandey, thanks for posting the HTML. Please see my answer and let me know how I can provide further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the id directly as id is unique:

```
$('#td_id').attr('id', 'tdid_test')
```

You don't need to use find id and define the id.

Also, you don't need to bind jQuery wrapper in `$(xHtml)` just `xHtml` would fine.

Comment: this will chnage the current element id that is on the page .I am getting the html from a id and putting that to a new id .there i want to chnage the id of the elment

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: See i have a tr from there i am getting the html by using .html() function now i am appending this html to a new div.So before appending to a new div i wantt to chnage the input type names and id .so that there will not be any duplicate id and name on the page when i submit the page

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you have a html code fragment stored in xHtml 
And you want to replace one `id` to a different `id` and restore that in same xHtml variable.

Why not use simple replace ? Like

```
xHtml = xHtml.replace("id", "tdid_test");
```

Comment: i want to change a partiular input type id

Comment: See i have a tr from there i am getting the html by using .html() function now i am appending this html to a new div.So before appending to a new div i wantt to chnage the input type names and id .

Comment: You can use replace function then, if you are sure what you are going to change and those are unique.

Comment: how i want to change all that before putting that in a new div

Answer (score 0):

Don't save as html, but as object.
Clone the object, change the id and append.

I have an example:

```
<p id="id1">Some text.</p>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
var x  = $("body");
y = x.clone(true);
y = $(y).find('#id1').attr('id', 'new_id');
$("body").append(y);
</script>
```

With your code:

```
var xHtml = $("#testid").clone(true);
xHtml = xHtml.find('#td_id').attr('id', 'tdid_test');
// now you can append
```

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that your html has (and does not have id `test_id`):

```
<tbody id ="testid">
```

But you're searching for:

```
$('#test_id')
```

And then you're searching for `#td_id` when the only other `id's` your have in the piece of html are: `test1, second2, second3`.

The code below will both pull out the correct html and change an id and display the modified markup.

[**WORKING JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/EQGe8/)

```
$(function() {
    var xHtml = $('#testid').html();
    //console.log( xHtml );
    xHtml = $(xHtml).find('#test1').attr('id', 'tdid_test').end().map(function () {
        console.log(this.outerHTML); return this.outerHTML;
    }).get().join('');
    console.log( xHtml );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a reference to HTML with your variable.
If you don't want an Id to be changed on the page - just clone your HTML part using [jQuery Clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) like so:

```
var $yourHTMLclone = xHtml.clone();
```

And then perform any changes you wish as it is an ordinary jQuery object.

Comment: what u r trying to do

Comment: Same, as the next answer. Don't you understand?